# How to query the whole collections including reference collections in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, collections, reference

I am using MongoDB. I have three collections. Posts, types and categories. Posts have reference ids for types and categories like the following;

*Post Collection* : {"name":"Post One", types:["typeoneId","typetwoId","typethreeId"], categories:["catOneId", "catTwoId", "catThreeId"]});

*Type Collection*: {"name": "Type One", "_id":"typeoneId"}, ...

*Category Collection*: {"name": "category one", "_id":"catOneId"}, ....

I want to query as one big collection including all informations about post, type and category.
How can I query in Mongodb?

Comment: You can't, MongoDB doesn't support joins.

Comment: Thanks, currently i am using mongoose.js also. So is this the only one way to gather all the information from mongoose and re-struct for the only one big collection? Is there any such kinds of function in mongoose,please?

Comment: mongoose has a populate function: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Uggh. Populate is not a join. It is a "pseudo" kind of reference that is typical to most ORM/ODM implementations. What it really does is go back to the database and fetches the "referenced" documents. Ask a real question to your use case and you will get a real answer. Open ended questions get bad answers. I think you just got a bad one while I was typing. And I checked, and I am right. Correct yes, but of course it does not actually answer what you want.

Comment: @NeilLunn I don't really think mine was a bad answer, intra-collection JOINs in MongoDB are client side as such the JOIN support comes from the ORM/ODM. Suggesting the standard function provided by Mongoose to solve JOINs doesn't seem like a bad answer to me

Comment: "There are no joins in MongoDB but sometimes we still want references to documents in other collections. This is where population comes in." This is what mongoose says.

Comment: Not a vaild argument. Mogoose **does not** "do magic". It only does illusions. You are still making multiple fetches to the database, regardless of the simplified syntax. This is very inefficient as your accepted answer points out. Do not do things the same way with NoSQL storage as you would with SQL (relational) storage. Otherwise there is no point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with MongoDB alone.  What you will have to do is run subsequent queries for type _ids in the `types` array to populate those (as well as categories).  This is one query for each POST and then two subsequent queries per post.  There may be faster ways to do this as well.

For Mongoose, you can use [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

```
Post.find().populate('types').populate('categories')
```